# How to resolve `this` in converting React module to ES6 class

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a `React` module that works fine in `ES5`.  I am converting it to `ES6` and using `6to5` for the conversion.  Everything transpiles fine, but I get a runtime error when I am trying to set my `props`.  When I drop a `debugger` and look at `this`, I see that `this` is the `EventEmitter` and not the class.  Here is my code:

```
var React = require('react');

import CalendarStore from './../stores/calendar.store.js';

function getAppointments() {
  return {appts: CalendarStore.getAppts()}
}

export default class extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props = {
      view: 'weeks'
    }
  }

  changeView(child, view) {
    this.setProps({view: view});
  }

  componentWillMount() {
     CalendarStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
  }

  _onChange() {
    this.setProps(getAppointments());
  }

  ....
};
```

The place I am having the issue is in my `changeView` function.  When it is `transpiled` down it looks like this:

```
  _onChange: {
      value: function _onChange() {
        this.setProps(getAppointments());
      },
      writable: true,
      configurable: true
    }
```

Again, inside that function, `this` is my `EventEmitter`.  What is the way to fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`this.setProps` is deprecated, use state for this.  It'll give you this warning in 0.13:

> Warning: setProps(...) is deprecated in plain JavaScript React classes.

Also es6 class methods aren't autobound, so you need to bind it manually.  You can either use `.bind(this)`, or use arrow functions.  For external emitters you do need to keep a reference, though.

You can just get rid of _onChange:

```
this._calendarListener = e => this.setState({things: e});
CalendarStore.addChangeListener(this._calendarListener);
```

Or bind in the constructor:

```
constructor(props){
   ...
   this._onClick = this._onClick.bind(this);
}
```

Don't forget to unbind the event in componentWillUnmount:

```
componentWillUnmount(){
    CalendarStore.removeChangeListener(this._onClick);
    // or 
    CalendarStore.removeChangeListener(this._calendarListener);
}
```

Adding event listeners should be done in componentDidMount, not componentWillMount.  The constructor replaces componentWillMount in es6 classes.

This code is very bad... you're overriding the props react sets:

```
this.props = {
  view: 'weeks'
}
```

Just replace all occurrences of 'props' with 'state' in your code, and all will be good.  Also you probably want the store's initial state.

```
this.state = {
  view: 'weeks',
  things: CalendarStore.getAppts()
}
```

---

Also, createClass isn't going away any time soon, so feel free to continue using it.  It's often simpler.  Stores should generally be handled by mixins, which is trivial with createClass, but more difficult to do right in es6 classes.  I have a small library for [mixins with react and es6 classes](https://github.com/brigand/react-mixin).

Comment: Can you show me a blog or somewhere that explains how stores should be handled by mixins?

Comment: Most flux implementations provide one.  The mixin handles getting initial state from the store, listening to the store, and doing a this.setState when there's a change.  It also cleans up the listener when the component is unmounted.  Here's an example of a [fluxxor store mixin](http://fluxxor.com/documentation/store-watch-mixin.html)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand what if i also use flow and set a default value like this? `_handleStoreChange = (state: Object = {}) => {..}` I get a syntax error with babel `Assigning to rvalue`

Comment: Maybe it's `state={}: Object` ?

Comment: It should be noted that React's component state is considered to be an anti-pattern, and should be replaced by a global state manager such as Redux or Flux.

Comment: @NathanCox it's not an anti-pattern. In many cases using redux or similar is good, but not always. Even the official redux faq doesn't recommend using redux for all applications and components. I use a mix of redux and component state, each when it's the best option.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/3bjdoe/state_is_an_antipattern/ basically describes why interal React state is an antipattern. Most of the big names in the React community that I follow go through great pains to never use internal state for these reasons.